# Construction of sequence with specific properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to costruct a sequence $(g_{n})_{n}$ such that it converges a.e to zero and $$\limsup\int g_{n}d\lambda=1,$$  $$\liminf\int g_{n}d\lambda=-1$$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.

I think $(g_{n})_{n}$ has to be a three step fuction of the form

$$g(x)_{n}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-1 &  \\ 
 0& \\ 
 1& 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

but I'm not quite sure what the support of each step for $g(x)_{n}$ has to be.

Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
g_n=
\begin{cases}I_{[n,n+1]}&\text{$n$} \,\text{even}\\
-I_{[-n-1,-n]} &n \,{\text{odd}}
\end{cases}
$$
for $n\geq1$.

Comment: and $g_{n}$ is measurable as composition of measurable functions,it was much easier than I thought.Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jonathan1234 Each $g_n$ is measurable because it is a characteristic function of a measurable set.  I don't see what composition has to do with it...  Note also that this example does better than go to zero almost everywhere; it goes to zero pointwise.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy here is to start with a nice example of a sequence of functions that converge pointwise or almost everywhere to zero, but which fail to integrate to zero in the limit.  For example, consider the sequence
$$ f_n = n \chi_{[0,1/n]}. $$

Observe that
$$ \int f_n = \int n \chi_{[0,1/n]} = n \mu([0,\tfrac{1}{n}]) = 1 $$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  On the other hand, for all $x\ne 0$, we have $f_n(x) \to 0$.  Thus $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n = 1$.  Now all we need to do is adjust the sign.  The usual trick is to multiply by $-1$ for odd $n$, i.e. define
$$ g_n = (-1)^n f_n = (-1)^n n \chi_{[0,1/n]}. $$
It can be verified that
$$ \int g_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n$ is even, and} \\ -1 & \text{if $n$ is odd}, \end{cases} $$
from which the desired result follows.